# Class calling in android development

Tags: java, android

i'm new to android development, how can i call a class to be performed when my application starts. Is there something i should put on the onCreate part to call a class? any tips for this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the problem? MyClass myInstance = new MyClass(); myInstance.do() ?

Comment: That way you won't get nowhere... http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423782/what-is-the-best-equivalent-of-a-main-function-for-an-android-app/14423821#14423821

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure to understand the building blocks (Activity, Intent, ...) of an Android application before you start coding. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html is a good starting point. The tutorial will answer your question.